# Create a barcode image in java using jasperreports, without saving the image on disk

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to create a barcode image in java using jasperreports, currently I'm doing this saving the image file on disk, but I need to do it without saving the image on disk. I need to create the barcode image in memory an then send it to iReport as a parameter.

This is what I have done:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String imagePath = "\\\\netw\\barCode.jpg";
parameters.put("rutaCodigoBarrasVal", imagePath);

Barcode barCode = BarcodeFactory.createPDF417("1234567890");
barCode.setDrawingText(false);
barCode.setBarHeight(33);
barCode.setBarWidth(207);

FileOutputStream fOS = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
BarcodeImageHandler.writeJPEG(barCode, fOS);
fOS.close();
```

What can I do?

Comment: I think you can use ByteArrayOutputStream instead of FileOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

You should first try to write the Barcode into a byte array or InputStream, looking at your library documentation.
JasperReports supports passing an image as a InputStream parameter, and draw that in the report.

```
InputStream imageStream = ...;
parametros.put("image", imageStream );
```

From JasperReports, receive that parameter as java.io.InputStream, then draw it with an image widget and the following properties:
Image Expression: $P{image}
Expression Class: java.io.InputStream

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Finally this is what I did using barcode4j library:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PDF417Bean barCode = new PDF417Bean();
boolean antiAlias = false;
int orientation = 0;
int dpi = 300;

BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, antiAlias, orientation);

BarcodeDimension dim = new BarcodeDimension(207, 42);
canvas.establishDimensions(dim);
barCode.setColumns(7);
barCode.generateBarcode(canvas, codeToConvert);
canvas.finish();

String mime = MimeTypes.MIME_JPEG;
os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

final BitmapEncoder encoder = BitmapEncoderRegistry.getInstance(mime);
encoder.encode(canvas.getBufferedImage(), os, mime, dpi);
fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
```